# Firebase Cloud Storage Do a WildCard Search Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Suppose I have this directory structure in the firebase cloud storage `gs://my-bucket/userData/`, and inside this directory I have multiple files with a similar name, like `some-file-1.json`, `some-file-21.json`, `some-file-34.json`.

My end goal is to get all these similar named files.

I'm guessing to do that, I need to do a wildcard search, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames). There it shows how to do it using the gcloud command line. How do I do that in `Nodejs` or `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage APIs do not support wildcard characters search of files, however, you can use prefixes to get a list of files that start with the same name prefix, which I assume will suite the needs of your app, here is an example implementation:

```
async function readFiles () {
   const [files] = await bucket.getFiles({ prefix: 'userData/some-file-'});
   files.forEach(file => {
       console.log(file.name);
   });
};
```

In this example you will log all the file names that start with `some-file-`.